# tkinter setting background color failure

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window of lines that I select a single line from with a search.

I highlight the line and return for processing.

When I select another item, I first attempt to unmark the 
previously selected line before highlighting the next selection by calling the 'mark' function with a flag for
mark/unmark.

The mark function computes the start and end-of-line (these
values have been verified to be correct.

The problem is that the MARK/UNMARK works only one time!
The selected line is marked and on the next selection, the
line is unmarked.  However, all further selections are not
marked.

```
print("Just line #: ", lidx, "  lend: ", lend)
text.tag_add("here",lidx,lend)
text.tag_add("back",lidx,lend)
if mark == True:
    print("Make Mark")
    text.tag_config("here", background="#e0e0e0")
else:
    print("Make Unmark")
    text.tag_config("back", background="#ffffff")
```

This is driving me somewhat Crazy. I have spent 30% of
my coding time on just this issue!!!!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information for anyone to do more than make wild guesses as to the actual problem - see [mcve] for the required level of detail for an answerable question.  My wild guess is that since you're never actually removing the "here" tag from previously-selected lines, the two background settings are trying to be applied to exactly the same text, and the wrong one is winning.

Comment: Thank you that HINT was all I needed.  It works fine now -- I attach the code fix:

Comment: text.tag_add("here",lidx,lend)
    text.tag_add("back",lidx,lend)
    if mark == True:
        text.tag_delete("back")
        text.tag_config("here", background="yellow")
    else:
        text.tag_delete("here")
        text.tag_config("back", background="#ffffff")